# xsd & xml with element order change

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I've an xml file which i have bound to an xsd schema. I want to create an xsl for the schema in such a way that whatever order i write the xml in it comes printed out in that order
for example:

```
'<employee>
<firstname>sultan</firstname>
<lastname>saadat</lastname>
</employee>'
```

If the above block is written like this:

```
 <employee>
    <lastname>saadat</lastname>
    <firstname>sultan</firstname>
    </employee>
```

It should come out in the same way when transformed and not in the wayy it is parsed? what could be the possible solutions?

having trouble with this xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resume>



  <professional-experience-section>
    <section-name>PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE</section-name>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <company>
      <name>Computer Sciences Corporation</name>
      <city>New York</city>
      <state>NY</state>
      <country>United States</country>
      <job-title>
        <title>Senior Software Engineer</title>
        <start-date>Aug 1996</start-date>
        <end-date>May 2010</end-date>
        <ongoing>false</ongoing>
        <job-description>
          <bullet-point>
            <statement>C#, Visual Basic, Asp.net</statement>
          </bullet-point>
          <bullet-point>
            <statement>Inspect completed work to ensure conformance to specifications, standards, and contract requirements.</statement>
          </bullet-point>
          <bullet-point>
            <statement>Another Work Description.</statement>
          </bullet-point>
        </job-description>
      </job-title>
    </company>
    <company>
      <name>Acme</name>
      <city>Silver Spring</city>
      <state>MD</state>
      <country>United States</country>


      </company>
  </professional-experience-section>


  <education-section>
    <section-name>EDUCATION</section-name>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <institution>
      <name>Allston Community College</name>
      <city>Akron</city>
      <state>MA</state>
      <country>United States</country>
      <degree>Bachelor of Art in Marketing Candidate</degree>
      <end-date>Jan 2020</end-date>
      <ongoing>true</ongoing>
      <expected-completion-date>Jan 2020</expected-completion-date>
      <completed></completed>
      <bullet-point>
        <statement>detail of what i did at the allston community college</statement>
      </bullet-point>
    </institution>



  </education-section>

  <additional-skills-section>
    <section-name>ADDITIONAL SKILLS</section-name>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <layout>1 Column</layout>
    <bullet-point>
      <statement>1</statement>
    </bullet-point>


  </additional-skills-section>
  <custom-section>
    <section-name>PUBLICATIONS</section-name>
    <layout>2</layout>
    <bullet-point>
      <statement>test</statement>
    </bullet-point>
  </custom-section>

  <custom-section>
    <section-name>AWARDS</section-name>
    <layout>2</layout>
    <bullet-point>
      <statement>test</statement>
    </bullet-point>
  </custom-section>

</resume>
```

Sample Stylesheet for one section, same goes for other sections:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/resume">
    <xsl:value-of select="/resume/contact-information/full-name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/resume/contact-information/address_line_1"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/resume/contact-information/address_line_2"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/resume/contact-information/city"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/resume/contact-information/state"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/resume/contact-information/country"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/resume/contact-information/phone"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="/resume/professional-experience-section/company"> 
        <!--for company name-->
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="city"/>, <xsl:value-of select="state"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
        <!--loop into job title-->
        <xsl:for-each select="job-title"> 
            <!--for job title-->
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/> 
            <!--for job start date and job end date-->
            <xsl:value-of select="start-date"/> – <xsl:value-of
                select="end-date"/>
            <!--Loop into job description-->
            <xsl:for-each select="job-description"> 
                <!--loop into each bullet point-->
                <xsl:for-each select="bullet-point">
                    <xsl:value-of select="statement"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: What exactly are you having a problem with: creating a schema that allows either order or creating an XSLT transform that respects that order? Those are two different things.

Comment: i have the schema i am looking for an xsl  that accounts for flexible xml order, so that if i change the xml, the xsl changes the output itself.

Comment: This is the same as your former question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214966/xml-sorting-using-xsl : Applying templeates with a sort order.

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways, but they tend to boil down to looping through tags that are "either lastname or firstname" in order. One example would be

```
<xsl:for-each select="firstname|lastname">
  <xsl:value-of select=".">
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: and it can fit into any number of elements?

Comment: @Sultan: Actually it's called the union operator: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-sets

Comment: please see the question, i have added the xml file thats giving me trouble, whenever user changes the order, i don't see anything projected on the transformed xsl. I hope everything is clear now

Comment: @Sultan: Your XML file is awfully formatted and I'm not going to even try to read it before you add linebreaks and indentation.

Comment: @Sultan: You forgot to post your XSLT. Also your XML sample is awfully long. Please post both, and trim the parts that aren't relevant to this problem.

Comment: I have posted the xsl and trimmed down the xml

Comment: @Sultan: From what I can tell, your XSLT transform looks fine. What does it output?

Comment: @Matti: The OP wants the elements always in certain, specified order -- your code still produces them in document order.

Comment: @Sultan: You asked this question more than once and accepted the answers. Why are you still posting this question?

Comment: @Dimitre: Well, his question was, to say the least, a bit vague. Juding by his comments, I do still think he wants things to be outputted in the same order as they appear in the document though.

Comment: @Matti: No, what he really wants, is to reorder the elements to match a specific order, specified as a parameter, or somewhere. He had a lot of similar questions in the past -- accepted!

Comment: @Dimitre: I see. @Sultan: If that is what you want, why are you contradicting yourself in your comments?

Comment: i was not articulate in my previous questions, i want the output to be printed out the way its in the XML document and not change it via a parameter. This was where i was contradicting my ownself. My simple question is how do i make the xsl in such a way that it prints in the same order as xml  no matter what.